# MVC4 Routing Issue with Optional Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a new route with that looks like this in the RouteConfig.cs.

```
routes.MapRoute("Edit_Personal", 
                "Edit/Personal/{userID}/{refKey}/{houseID}", 
                 new {controller = "Edit", action = "Personal", 
                      userID = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                      refKey = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                      houseID = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

This route works fine if I pass in something like:

```
Edit/Personal/78887/abcd/

UserID = 78887
RefKey = abcd
HouseID = null
```

However, if the RefKey is never passed (it's optional), but a HouseID is passed, I get this as the result (the URL):

```
Edit/Personal/78887//88881   <--- Notice the two slashes between the numbers.

UserID = 78887
RefKey = 88881
HouseID = null
```

The results I expected are:

```
UserID = 78887
RefKey = null
HouseID = 88881
```

If you notice, the RefKey should be NULL, however, it's binding the HouseID into the RefKey parameter.

Is there a way to correct this?  Am I missing something?

Comment: You can do this with a question mark, like this: `"Edit/Personal/{userID}/{refKey?}/{houseID}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define multiple routes like below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "WithAll",
    "{controller}/{action}/{UserID}/{RefKe}/{HouseID}",
    new{ controller = "Edit",action = "Personal"});

routes.MapRoute(
     "WithoutRefke",
     "{controller}/{action}/{UserID}/{HouseID}",
     new{controller = "Edit",action = "Personal"});

routes.MapRoute(
     "WithoutRefkeAndHouseID",
     "{controller}/{action}/{UserID}",
     new{controller = "Edit",action = "Personal",UserID= UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Take a look at the following link for more details:
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx/